# Can't update shopping cart for more than one item, works fine for a single item, otherwise only the first one gets updated

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I am trying to update the quantity of the products in the shopping cart by changing the number in the dropdown. If the cart has two or more items then only the first one works and the qty doesn't change for the other items even after changing it in the dropdown. I am getting the corresponding "productid" and "size" from the HTML form and trying to manipulate the sqlite database using these three values.
(Wondering if there is a way to get the "qty" value of only the item whose qty is being changed from the dropdown?)
Since request.form.get() only sends the first value back I was thinking of using request.form.getlist(). But then I have to figure out how to enter the arrays(eg. qtychanged[],productid[] and size[] into the Cart1 table. (Attaching the HTML file as Template)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="en">

 <head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/, alternative themes at https://bootswatch.com/ -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- https://favicon.io/emoji-favicons/money-mouth-face/ -->
    <!--<link href="/static/favicon.ico" rel="icon">-->

    <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.jcarousel.js"> 
</script>

</head>
<body>


<body>


    <form action="/updatecart" method="post">

     {% for item in shoppingcart %}

  <div class="Tcard">
    <div class='container2'>
      <p style="text-align:center">{{ item. name }}</p>
      <p class = "image"><img src= "{{ url_for('static', filename = item.image) }}" alt="Top 1" width ="100px" height = "100px"></p>
      <p class="price">Price: ${{ item.price }}</p>

      <label for="qty">Qty:</label>

          <select name = "qtydropdown" class = "qtydropdown" id = "mySelect"  onchange='this.form.submit()'>
               <option value="{{ item.qty }}">{{ item.qty }}</option>
                <option value="0">0 - Remove</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>

            <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>

          <p class = "fontgrp">Size: {{ item.size }}</p>
          <p class = "fontgrp"><b>Total Cost: {{ item.total | usd }}</b></p>
      </div>
    </div>

 <div>
    <input id="productid" name="productid" type="hidden" value="{{ item.productid }}">
    <input id="size" name="size" type="hidden" value="{{ item.size }}">
 </div>

 {% endfor %}

 <div>
<input class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Grand Total: {{ grandtotal | usd }}">
</div>
<br>
<div>
<a href="/checkout" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Checkout</a>
  <!--<input form action = "/checkout" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Checkout">-->
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
@app.route("/updatecart", methods = [ "POST"])    
def updatecart():

if request.method == "POST":
            
            shoppingcart = db.execute("select * from cart1") 
            
    #getting the qty from the html dropdown         
            qtychanged = request.form.get("qtydropdown")
        
     # productid corresponding to the qty       
            productid = request.form.get("productid")
            
      # size corresponding to the qty  
            size = request.form.get("size")
           
        
            for rows in shoppingcart:
                if int(qtychanged) == 0:
                            
                            
                            shoppingcart = db.execute("update cart1 set qty = :qty where productid = :productid and size = :size",
                            productid = productid,
                            size = size,
                            qty = qtychanged)
                            
                            
                            shoppingcart = db.execute("delete from cart1 where qty = :qty", qty = qtychanged)
                            
                            shoppingcart = db.execute("select * from cart1")
                            
                            if not shoppingcart:
                                return apology("Cart is empty")
                         
                               
                if len(shoppingcart)!=0:
                                       
                            shoppingcart = db.execute("select * from cart1 where productid = :productid and size = :size",
                            productid = productid,
                            size = size)
                            
                            
                            shoppingcart = db.execute("update cart1 set qty = :qty where productid = :productid and size = :size",
                            qty = qtychanged,
                            productid = productid,
                            size = size)
                     
                            shoppingcart = db.execute("select productid, name, size, qty, price, image, (qty * price) as total from cart1") 
                            if not shoppingcart:
                                return apology("Cart is empty")
                                
                            grandtotal = 0
                            
                            for row in shoppingcart:
                             
                                total = row["qty"] * float(row["price"])
                       
                        
                                grandtotal = grandtotal + total
                                return render_template("testcartlayout.html", shoppingcart = shoppingcart, total = total, grandtotal = grandtotal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the HTML works in the question works as expected, there are a number of improvements that could be made to the Python code to ensure it produces the results that you want, or at least give you some pointers.

- There is no need to `SELECT` all the rows and loop over them.  Using SQL you can generally operate on all the rows that you want in a single statement.
- To find out if the cart is empty it's more efficient to use `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM cart1` to retrieve the number of rows - rather than retrieving all the rows can call `len` on them.
- In the `DELETE` case, if `productid` and `size` uniquely identify a row, you `delete it immediately using these criteria, there is no need to do an` UPDATE` first.
- If you have deleted a row there is no further update to be done, so the `DELETE` and `UPDATE` sections should be in an `if/else`
- `grandtotal` can be computed in the database: `SELECT SUM (qty * price) FROM cart1` - no need to `SELECT` and loop!
- `total` is always going to be the `total` computed for the last row in the selection: this doesn't seem very useful (and it isn't computed if we compute `grandtotal` in the database).

The function below shows how you might improve the existing method.  Note that:

- I don't know the details of you flask setup, so it's just a normal function; flask things like `render_template` and `apology` have been removed
- I don't know exactly what `db` is: you might need to adjust the handling of the query results

```py
def updatecart(qtychanged, productid, size):

    # SELECT COUNT to get the number of rows in the table
    # without retrieving all of them.
    result = db.execute("select count(1) from cart1")
    shoppingcart = result.fetchone()[0]
    # If the cart is empty there is no point trying to do anything
    if not shoppingcart:
        return "Cart is empty"

    if int(qtychanged) == 0:
        # Delete unwanted product from the cart.
        # Assuming productid and size uniquely identify an
        # item in the cart, just delete no need to update
        db.execute(
            "delete from cart1 where productid = :productid and size = :size",
            productid=productid,
            size=size,
        )
        # Apologise if the cart is empty
        result = db.execute("select count(1) from cart1")
        shoppingcart = result.fetchone()[0]
        if not shoppingcart:
            return "Cart is empty"
    else:
        # We're not deleting, so let's update.
        db.execute(
            "update cart1 set qty = :qty where productid = :productid and size = :size",
            qty=qtychanged,
            productid=productid,
            size=size,
        )
    shoppingcart = db.execute(
        "select productid, name, size, qty, price, image, (qty * price) as total from cart1"
    )

    # Declare total to avoid error in return
    # In the original code, total would be the total computed
    # for the last row in the cart, which doesn't seem useful.
    total = 0

    # Compute the total price
    res = db.execute("""SELECT SUM(qty * price) FROM cart1""")
    grandtotal = res.fetchone()[0]

    return shoppingcart, total, grandtotal
```

I wrote some code to test drive the function: you can run it by pasting the function into a file, pasting the code below after the function code and calling `python myfile` - you use it to experiment if you want.  The only external dependency is `sqlalchemy`, which I used to emulate `db`.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import dqlalchemy as sa
    engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
    with engine.connect() as db:
        db.execute(
            """CREATE TABLE cart1 (
          productid INTEGER,
          name TEXT,
          size TEXT,
          qty INTEGER,
          price INTEGER,
          image TEXT
        )"""
        )
        ins = """INSERT INTO cart1
                 (productid, name, size, qty, price, image)
                 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""
        data = [
            (1, "Hat", "L", 1, 10, ""),
            (2, "Coat", "M", 5, 100, ""),
            (3, "Shirt", "M", 3, 20, ""),
        ]
        # Test 1: empty cart returns message
        db.execute(ins, data[0])
        res = updatecart(0, 1, "L")
        assert res == "Cart is empty", f"Expected empty message got {res}"
        # Reset the database
        db.execute("""DELETE FROM cart1""")
        # Test 2: update a row
        db.execute(ins, *data)
        # Buy two more hats
        resultobj, total, grandtotal = updatecart(3, 1, "L")
        rows = resultobj.fetchall()
        assert len(rows) == 3, f"Expected 3 got {len(rows)}"
        assert grandtotal == 590, f"Expected 590 got {grandtotal}"
        # Reset the database
        db.execute("""DELETE FROM cart1""")
        # Test 3: delete a row
        db.execute(ins, *data)
        # Remove the shirts
        resultobj, total, grandtotal = updatecart(0, 3, "M")
        rows = resultobj.fetchall()
        assert len(rows) == 2, f"Expected 2 got {len(rows)}"
        assert grandtotal == 510, f"Expected 510 got {grandtotal}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to improve the codes. I am well aware that I am repeating too much but by repeating and printing the table every time I change something I know if I am doing the right thing or not. :)  That's how I know that the template is returning only the first value of "qtychanged " even if I change the dropdown value for the second item in the cart, trying to figure out how to rectify that. :)